# What does this error mean and how do I stop this?

Tags: php

I am unable to get past this error that is occuring.
`Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Duplicate entry '{email address}' for key 'email' in C:\xampp\htdocs\FINAL PROJECT\php\process-signup.php:42 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\FINAL PROJECT\php\process-signup.php(42): mysqli_stmt->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\FINAL PROJECT\php\process-signup.php on line 42`
Here is my code:

```
<?php

if (empty($_POST["name"])){
    die("Name is required.");
}

if (! filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    die("Valid email is required.");

}

if (strlen($_POST["password"])<8) {
    die("Password must be at least 8 characters long.");            
}

if (! preg_match("/[a-z]/i", $_POST["password"])) {
    die("Password must contain at least one letter");
}

if (! preg_match("/[0-9]/", $_POST["password"])) {
    die("Password must contain at least one number");
}

if ($_POST["password"] !== $_POST["confirmpassword"]) {
    die("Passwords must match in order for you to continue");
}

$password_hash = password_hash($_POST["password"], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$mysqli = require __DIR__ . "/database.php";

$sql = "INSERT INTO user (name, email, password_hash) VALUES (?,?,?)";

$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();

if (! $stmt->prepare($sql)){
    die("SQL Error: " . $mysqli->error);
}

$stmt->bind_param("sss", $_POST["name"], $_POST["email"], $password_hash);

if ($stmt->execute()) {
    echo "signup successful";
} else {
    if ($mysqli->errno === 1062) {
        die("email already taken.");
    }
    die($mysqli->error . " " . $mysqli->errno);
}
```

I am new to php and I am trying to complete a simple login, using a tutorial online. The tutorial has not touched on this error and I am completely stuck on what to do. I am trying to defensively program a message to appear should the email already be in the database table (I am aware that it is already). Should the email already be in, I need the server side validation to inform the user that the email is already taken etc.

**EDIT**

I have amended the code to use try/catch, thank you to the person who told me that! The code is now working!

Comment: `Duplicate entry '{email address}' for key 'email'` You're trying to insert an email address that already exists. Query the database to see if the email exists before you try to insert it.

Comment: You're following an old tutorial. `mysqli` now throws an exception when a SQL error happens, it doesn't return false. So you need to use `try/catch` rather than `if/else`

Comment: @aynber Did you notice that they have error checking code that's intended to report this?